Как использовать сертификат для номера WhatsApp Business API, если все проверки пройдены(есть уведомление об этом), но статус «в рассмотрении»?
Столкнулась с задачей интеграции номера WhatsApp Business API, который будет использоваться для работы чат-бота. Номер хотели использовать в приложении, созданном в Facebook for Developers, и на данный момент:
Все проверки пройдены, но общий статус все еще отображается как «в рассмотрении».
Сертификат для номера получен через WhatsApp Manager.
Требуется настроить использование сертификата в приложении, чтобы номер мог начать отправлять сообщения.
Вопросы:

Где именно необходимо указать сертификат?
Есть ли возможность использовать сертификат для отправки сообщений в статусе «в рассмотрении»? Или обязательно дождаться полного подтверждения всех проверок?
Какие шаги мне нужно выполнить для корректного добавления номера в приложение, чтобы обеспечить успешную отправку сообщений ботом?
Может, чтобы статус изменился нужно сделать что-то другое?
Когда мы добавляем в приложение этот номер, он нам пишет, что нельзя.

Буду признательна за рекомендации и пошаговые инструкции, если кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией!

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask //Вам следует разделить ваш вопрос на подвопросы, тогда будет больше вероятности получить ответ. 1 вопрос в вопросе
